# Every vector space of dimension $\kappa$ has $\kappa$ elements when $\kappa$ is at least $\aleph_1$

Tags: logic, vector-spaces, model-theory

[image]
I'm reading this proof from http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/logic/vspaces.

But I don't see why every vector space of dimension $\kappa$ has $\kappa$ elements.

Also, I know that vector spaces of finite dimensions are an isomorphism. But I'm not sure how they reached the conclusion $T_{VS}$ is $\kappa$-categorical.

Thanks!

Comment: Re: the first question, what can you say right off the bat about the cardinality of a $K$-vector space of dimension $\kappa$? Can you find an expression for it?

Comment: isn't the cardinality of the vector space $\kappa ^ {\kappa }$? I guess the question is : is $\kappa^{\kappa }=\kappa$, when $\kappa  \geq \aleph_1$. I know that $\kappa \cdot \kappa= \kappa $. But I'm not sure if $\kappa^{\kappa }=\kappa$ since $\kappa$ is uncountable

Comment: We will in fact never have $\kappa^\kappa=\kappa$, by Cantor's theorem (note that $2^\kappa\le\kappa^\kappa$). However, the cardinality of the vector space is **not** $\kappa^\kappa$. Suppose I have a basis $B$ of a vector space - how are elements of the space represented, in terms of $B$? What does that tell you about the cardinality?

Comment: So each element can be represented as a linear combination of the basis. So the cardinality of the vector space is the the cardinality of the basis? So I guess now the question is: what is the cardinality of the basis of such vector field? Suppose the $K$-vector space is $\kappa$-dimensional. Then the cardinality of the basis is $\kappa$.

Comment: It's not that simple. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a one-dimensional vector space over itself. Its cardinality is much greater than its dimension. Think about what a linear combination is, precisely.

Comment: hmmm... So a linear combination is a polynomial of degree 1 over the field $K$?

Comment: I think it's better to think of it as a finite sequence of pairs $(a_1v_1, a_2v_2,...,a_nv_n)$ with $a_i\in K$ and $v_i\in B$. So now you need to count such sequences. It will help to count separately based on length: how many are there of length $1$? What about length $2$?

Comment: Sorry do you mean the length of of the sequence?

Comment: Just a quick question: If two K-vector spaces have the same cardinality. Does that mean their bases have the same cardinality? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I mean the length of the sequence. Re: your second question, definitely not - consider $\mathbb{R}$ vs. $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces.

Comment: So do we get |V|=|K||B|? i.e cardinality of the vector space= cardinality of field times cardinality of the basis?